# How to I get key and value from json object inside json object

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring

This is my one json object:
`JSONObject childDepenObj = new JSONObject();`

I am put key and value like that:

```
childDepenObj.put("COL_CHLD_NULFY", gridObjectArray[86]);
childDepenObj.put("COL_CHLD_MAN", gridObjectArray[87]);
```

Here I have one more Json Object:

```
JSONObject gridObject = new JSONObject();
```

In that I am put above json object as value:

```
gridObject.put("hiddenObj", childDepenObj);
```

So, My question is how I get first Json Object key and values in frontend,

I am using like:
`response.hiddenobj;`

then resonse is coming but it coming under hiddenobj, I want direct first json object key and value like:
`response.COL_CHLD_NULFY;`
when I triyng like this it saying undefined,
any help?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can get the value you want by accessing

```
response.hiddenObj.COL_CHLD_NULFY;
```

However, if you want to be able to access it like

```
response.COL_CHLD_NULFY;
```

then just return the `childDepenObj` as the response.

---

How the current JSON response looks:

```
{
  "hiddenObj": {
    "COL_CHLD_NULFY": <<gridObjectArray[86] value>>,
    "COL_CHLD_MAN": <<gridObjectArray[87] value>>,
  }
}
```

How you want it to look:

```
{
  "COL_CHLD_NULFY": <<gridObjectArray[86] value>>,
  "COL_CHLD_MAN": <<gridObjectArray[87] value>>,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    JSONObject childDepenObj = new JSONObject();
    childDepenObj.put("COL_CHLD_NULFY", gridObjectArray[86]); 
    childDepenObj.put("COL_CHLD_MAN", gridObjectArray[87]);

    JSONObject gridObject = new JSONObject();
    gridObject.put("hiddenObj", childDepenObj);

    output = response.hiddenobj.COL_CHLD_NULFY
```

Try this...